# Android 4.2.2 Region.getBoundaryPath() drawing

Tags: android, drawing

I wrote a code and tested on android 4.0.3; everything worked fine. Now I tested it on android 4.2.2 and a filling method is not working. I have simplified the problem and here is a dummy code which shows the real problem:

```
Paint testpaint = new Paint();
testpaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
testpaint.setAlpha(255);
testpaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

Path p = new Path();
p.moveTo(10, 10);
p.lineTo(200, 10);
p.lineTo(200, 250);
p.lineTo(10, 200);
p.lineTo(10,10);
p.close();

RectF rectF = new RectF();
Region rr = new Region();
p.computeBounds(rectF, false);
rr.setPath(p,new Region((int) rectF.left, (int) rectF.top, (int) rectF.right, (int) rectF.bottom));

//works
RegionIterator ri = new RegionIterator(rr);
Rect rect = new Rect();
int count = 0;
while (ri.next(rect)){
    canvas.drawRect(rect, testpaint);
    count++;
}

//works
canvas.drawPath(p, testpaint);

//doesn't work
canvas.drawPath(rr.getBoundaryPath(), testpaint);


//works
Path outline = rr.getBoundaryPath();
Path newpath = new Path();
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setScale(1, 1, 0, 0);
outline.transform(matrix,newpath);
canvas.drawPath(newpath, testpaint);
```

The first and second draw makes it's job but the third doesn't. If i make a zero rotation then it works too. Do anyone have an idea why (I need the getBoundaryPath version), and why did it work on 4.0.3?

Comment: And another test:
      //works
      Path outline = rr.getBoundaryPath();
   Path newpath = new Path();
   Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
   matrix.setScale(1, 1, 0, 0);
   outline.transform(matrix,newpath);
      canvas.drawPath(newpath, testpaint);

Answer (score -1):

`getBoundaryPath()` returns `bool` as far as i know. Maybe try `rr.boundaryPath` which should return the path.

Comment: No it doesn't. As the name suggests, it returns a Path.